# AngularJS: preferred way of calling a $scope-exposed, controller-defined function on a $scope-exposed, controller-defined model

Tags: angularjs

You have a controller, a model exposed on its scope that the user can manipulate in a template, a function in the controller that acts on that model which a click-handler in the template will invoke. When and why would you prefer to either:

- invoke the function with the model as an argument through the template
- invoke the function with the model closed over in the scope

[Working fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/yangmillstheory/TqL4H/)

EDIT: In [this video](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-defining-a-method-on-the-scope) by John Lindquist, he advocates use of the first form, claiming that it makes it testing easier. I can agree with that, in that a test for a controller method could be more readable if passing in an argument.

Template:

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div class="container demo-container" ng-controller="MyCtrl">

        <label for="model_input">
            Model:
            <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="model" name="model_input"/>
        </label>

        <p>
            Invoke function with <strong>'{{model}}'</strong> explicitly through template
        </p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="fn_through_tpl(model)">
            Click
        </button>

        <p>
            Invoke function with <strong>'{{model}}'</strong> implicitly through controller
        </p>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="fn_through_ctrl()">
            Click
        </button>

    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])

.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.model = "my model";

    $scope.fn_through_tpl = function (model) {
        alert(model + " through template!");
    }

    $scope.fn_through_ctrl = function () {
        alert($scope.model + " through $scope!");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, I'd recommend the latter - what you call function through controller.  With two-way data binding, there's no need to pass the model back as it's already been updated.  It is redundant and confusing for readers.  Instead, invoke behaviors on the controller that act on the model.

I think the former pattern is appropriate when the model is or contains an array, and you want to expose controller actions that act upon the array elements.  For example:

```
<div ng-repeat="comment in post.comments">
    {{ comment.message }}
    <button ng-click="deleteComment(comment)">Delete comment</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a great example of when the first form is appropriate.